# Wierd Ethernet Color Wiring / Rj-45 Connectors

Tags: ethernet

My friend recent bought a house.

All the rooms are wired for CAT5.

In the garage theirs a networking panel that has some sort of punch panel and then all the CAT5 cable routed to the rooms.

Problem we are having is that the RJ-45 connectors that are currently on ends in the panel to connect to a router/modem etc. for some reason dont fit. They are very hard to connect/disconnect. We actually broke 1 because it got stuck in the Cisco router we were using.

Any info on abnormal RJ-45 connectors?

Also, the CAT5 cable that is routed through the house is using some non-standard wire color.

[image: Normal CAT5]

Instead of these colors, the wires we have are as follows: Wire 1 is a light green, 2 is Dark Green, 3 is yellow, 4 is Dark Blue, 5 is light blue, 6 is orange, 7 is tan and 8 is brown.

I havent been able to find any information on this type of color scheme for CAT5 wiring.

We want to cut the current RJ-45 ends and put new RJ-45 connectors on the cables to fit.

Anyone have any information on wiring order or know anything about this color scheme or weird fitting RJ-45 connectors?

Comment: The colours you describe sound like they just use light colours instead of stripes - the wiring sequence is exactly as normal just striped green = light green, striped orange = light orange (i.e. yellow), striped blue = light blue, striped brown = tan. Perfectly standard wiring scheme, just slightly different wire jacket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the RJ45 modular connectors go I have seen cheap ones not fit well. I like Leviton stuff myself.

I have seen colors messed up like this. The way wiring code works White/Green  Green/White with first color being the dominate one, so this would be your translation.

Light Green =  White / Green
Dark Green =  Green /White
Yellow = White / Orange
Dark Blue = Blue / White
Light Blue = White / Blue
Orange = Orange /White
Tan = White / Brown
Brown = Brown /White

There are 2 color codes 568A w/g g/w w/o bl/w w/bl o/w w/br br/w and there is 568B that the orange and green pair are swapped and it goes  w/o o/w w/g bl/w w/bl g/w w/br br/w. You need to look where the cable is punched to the patch panel It was say 568A or B. Unless your router needs a crossover (most don't any more) you wire the RJ45 modulator end the same as it is punched on the panel. Hold the end you hand with the clip away from you and the left side is pin 1.

I hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

just get yourself new RJs and repalce every RJ you have . non-standard connections will drive you nuts .